# All instances of AVPlayer mute and refuse to play

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, avaudioplayer, avplayer

iOS 8.1

I have a number of instances of AVPlayer playing sound effects, I also have an instance of AVAudioPlayer playing music.

Randomly when using the app the interface will hang for a split second and the music will stop, after this point none of the AVPlayer plays will trigger.

I'm getting nothing in the log and can't seem to find any reason for the players to stop. I have been unable to reproduce the issue reliably, it seems to happen without any direct cause.

Interestingly even when using MPMusicPlayerController in place of AVAudioPlayer I am experiencing the same problem: Music from my iTunes library will stop just as the AVAudioPlayer tracks did.

Has anybody experienced anything like this? I am completely stumped.

```
  NSURL *urlRadio;

    if (is2P){

        urlRadio = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"retroremix" ofType:@"mp3"]];

    } else {

        urlRadio = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pixel" ofType:@"mp3"]];

    }

  audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlRadio error:nil];

  if (!ownMusic){

     [audioPlayer play];

        } else {

             [mDRMAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting nothing in the log

I suggest registering for the `AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification`. Then you'll get something in the log! The problem, I'm guessing, is that the media services daemon is being hosed. You might be crashing it, or some other app might be doing it. I'm guess that you're doing it, but that's neither here nor there; if you discover that you are the cause, you'll need to figure out why. Either way, you need to be prepared for this possibility. If the notification fires, you must throw away all audio and video players and recreate them from scratch.

(And see Apple's Q&A document on this topic: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1749/.)

Comment: Thanks! I had registered for interruptions but not this.